# Get the geo located Country and State in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, geoip

I am making a plugin to display estimate shipping/delivery time depend on visitor IP address. To do this I am using `WC_Geolocation` but using this I can get only visitor country code like `US` `CA` etc how can I get visitor state name if county is US .

```
 $geoData   = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
 $country   = $geoData['country'];
 echo $country;
```

will output country code. how to get state name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the **geolocated state**:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
$geo_instance  = new WC_Geolocation();
// Get geolocated user geo data.
$user_geodata = $geo_instance->geolocate_ip();

// Get current user GeoIP Country
$country = $user_geodata['country'];

// Get current user GeoIP State
$state   = isset($user_geodata['state']) ? $user_geodata['state'] : '';
```

Comment: how can i find which array key contain $user_geodata like `country`  `state` etc

Comment: if you use `print_r($user_geodata)` or `var_dump($user_geodata)` you will see that you get an array of `country` + `state` …

Comment: Thanks  you save my day

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i want to use this in my custom plugin. so i write your code in my custom plugin file and then echo $country. then i am not getting country code . when i write  print_r($geo_instance); then i am getting WC_Geolocation Object ( )